# Creata a HABTM Object in Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I cant figure out how to create a relationship between a player and roster through a HABTM relationship called players_rosters, but in my console how do i create a relation between the two with attributes.

Players_rosters consists of roster_id and player_id. The relationship works but how can i create the association with manual attributes.

```
r = Roster.find(1)

r.create(:player_id => 1)
```

This doesnt work, but how could i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're finding the roster:

```
r = Roster.find(1)
player = r.players.create(:name => 'Joe')
```

Using your example of setting the player's id:

```
r.players.create(:id => 22, :name => 'Joe')
```

Find the first player and add them to the Roster with id of 22:

```
# Then you can assign as follows:
player = Player.first
roster = Roster.find(22)
player.rosters << roster
```

Or, to assign the player to only a single roster:

```
player = Player.first
player.rosters = [Roster.find(22)]
player.save
```

The `save` may not be necessary. I don't recall if assignment triggers a save like appending to an association.

Comment: Tried this but didnt work :/ player = r.players.create(:player_id => 1)                                                        i get NoMethodError for your second example :(

Comment: You wouldn't pass the player id to create. You're actually creating a player at that point. So `r.players.create(:number => '47', :name => 'Joe Blow')`. If you wanted to set the id explicitly in create, try passing :id. `r.players.create(:id => 10, :name => 'Fred', :number => '47')`.

Comment: r.players.create(:id => 1) creates a new player with id 1 and creates the relationship between the two, but how can i create a relationship between existing players and rosters?

Comment: Your 4th example gives me NoMethodError: undefined method 'roster='

Comment: I already had has_and_belongs_to_many :rosters, tried belongs_to :roster but didn't make any difference

Comment: See the latest update re: HABTM (which you do state in your initial q).